# Conditional Probability and Confusion Matrices

Tags: probability

Suppose we have three classes $A,B$ and $C$. Is it always the case that $$P(\text{Actual=A}|\text{Observed=A})+P(\text{Actual=A}|\text{Observed=B})+P(\text{Actual=A}|\text{Observed=C}) = 1$$

Or more generally, if have $n$ classes $A_1, \dots, A_n$, is it always the case that:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} P(\text{Actual} = A_i|\text{Observed}=A_k) = 1$$ for any $i$ in $\{1, \dots, n \}$?

Comment: Welcome to CV! Can you clarify what you mean by "observed"?

Answer (score 1):

(EDIT: I did not fully understand you are talking about confusion matrices and thought this was just a question about conditional probabilities, and I don't fully understand confusion matrices, so my answer may not make sense under that, though based on a comment below, it seems like it's the same concept here)

No, but perhaps somewhat related, there is the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability), which states that if you have a finite (or even countably infinite) partition of the sample space (ie disjoint events whose union is the entire space), denoted $B_1,\dots,B_n$, then for an event $A$ we have that
$$P(A) = \sum_n P(A|B_n)P(B_n)$$

So you also need to tack on $P(Observed = A_k)$ for each $k$ in your second equation.

To really illustrate, suppose I have $A,B$, and suppose I know that no matter what I observe, the actual is $A$. Then 
$$P(Actual = A|Observed = B) = P(Actual = A|Observed = A) = 1$$
and so your equation cannot be true.

Comment: This answer is just as correct in the context of confusion matrices.

Comment: ah okay, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I mixed your problem with another one, my apology. As @doubled suggested, your equation is not equal to one.
The one I am confused with is below.

$P(\text{Actual=A}|\text{Observed=A})+P(\text{Actual=B}|\text{Observed=A})+P(\text{Actual=C}|\text{Observed=A}) = 1$

This one is actually equal to one.

> Yes, You are right. As long as all these classes are all the possible classes. A heuristic way to think this is that all P(Actual=A|Observed=Ak) for k = 1, 2, ..., n represents all possible ways that you can get actual A. And this A here already happened. Therefore the probability is 1. Here all events(Actual=A|Observed=Ak) for k = 1, 2, ..., n are disjoint.

Comment: How can this be the case... the simplest case, as in my answer, is if conditional on any observation, the probability of Actual A is 1... then by your argument the probability is strictly greater than 1..? See my answer

Comment: Your last equation isn't right. If A dooms to happen then P(Actual=A|Observed=B)=P(Actual=A|Observed=A)=P(Actual=A). Notice in guetstats's second equation, there are total n Ai classes. One single event can't have probability 1.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand how this can possibly be true, unless "class" has some meaning I don't understand. Maybe this has to do with what it means to be 'observed,' but I still can't possible imagine this holding.. this completely flies in the face of the law of total probability.